# Is there any logs for Email Alerts to verify if email was delivered?

Tags: email-alert, logging

I've created Email Alert with Process Builder to send email notifications to newly added users in my custom table. How can I see the status of this email sending? I've found the `Email Log Files` functionality, but there is no status of delivery and it's not so handy to download zip with csv inside every time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Setup>Debug>Email Log Files?

> Email logs describe all emails sent through salesforce.com and can be used to help identify the status of an email delivery. Email logs are CSV files that provide information such as the email address of each email sender and its recipient, the date and time each email was sent, and any error code associated with each email. Logs are only available for the past 30 days.

Comment: I've described in my question that Email Log Files are not appropriate